# Android - How to center a title (TextView) in a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-toolbar

On the left of my toolbar I have a logo, and I want to center a TextView in the same toolbar to act as my title. For some reason, the title does not center, and is instead on the right. Here is my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Register">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentInsetLeft="5dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="60dp"
            android:maxWidth="60dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/scss.ttf");
        setContentView(R.layout.frag_register_name);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3f9845")));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Does anybody know why the title does not center in the toolbar? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem. The quickest one would be to change your TextView as follows.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" // Fill parent
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:gravity="center" // Make the text center aligned
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This makes sure that your text would cover the entire space next to the icon and center the text within it. You dont even need a `LinearLayout` for that. It can be removed and it'll still work.

Answer (score 0):

If you give `gravity` as center then it should work. One more way is to setting width of your textview as match_parent and giving `text_alignment` as center

Answer (score -1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_add_medication"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow - You can add some meaningful explanations also to your answer. Only the code snippet wont help users in most of the cases to identify the route causes / solutions even though the code is right.