# How to get a label in the Android action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

As the title suggests, I want to put some text in the action bar. Firstly, here's a mockup (in Paint!) of what I'm imagining:

[image]

I'm really struggling with this. In my activity I put:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen, menu);
  return true;
}
```

And in the menu folder I put main_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item android:id="@+id/user_level"
    android:title="Administrator"
    android:showAsAction="withText" />

</menu>
```

So I have 2 questions:

#### Question 1

Why at the very least the solution above doesn't  show the text `Administrator`

#### Question 2

Once it's showing the text, how do I make it appear like a label (with the grey background and the rounded corners, etc)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try android:showAsAction="always|withText"  in your menu item. And try adding android:orderInCategory="50". 50 is just a random number.

Comment: Are you using a Toolbar (the new material design way) or an ActionBar?

Comment: for appcompat activity
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/user_level"
    android:title="Administrator"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>  
</menu>

Comment: @comeback4you can you please provide code as answers, not comments?

Comment: For a Toolbar example, you can see this post on centering a text. You can easily change that to be on the right.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640629/android-how-to-center-a-title-textview-in-a-toolbar

Comment: @isnotmenow - thanks. That fixed the text appearing. Do you have any ideas on how to do the styling?

Comment: please read at my answer below..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custom menu item is what you need for your second question.

first you need to make custom layout for your menu item.

**cust_menu.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/admin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Administrator"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="@drawable/my_shape";
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

for making rounded grey square background you need to make custom shape file and set it to your `TextView` background.

**my_shape.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

    <solid android:color="#e3e3e3" />

</shape>
```

now your menu item will go like this.

**main.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/admin"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/cust_menu"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

and in java class simply do this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

let me know if any doubts.

for more information visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17972602/5148289)

**EDIT :**

you can access your `TextView` this way.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    View view = menu.findItem(R.id.admin).getActionView();
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textID);

    // do your stuff

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

happy coding.

Comment: This is very cool, thank you. One question; how can I set the right margin of the label to a few px? At the moment it is right up against the right edge of the screen.

Comment: it is custom layout you can play with it. set marging to textview or wrap that textview inside linearlayout or relativelayout and give padding to it.

Comment: I tried adding `android:layout_marginRight="5dp"` to the textview and it made no difference?

Comment: then try second way. wrap it inside one of the layout and add `android:paddingRight` to it. i'm sure it will work.

Comment: Thank you - that worked. One final question, how do I make the background of the label change colour to black when a user taps it?

Comment: you need to make a selector for that. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386035/custom-selector-for-list-background) will help you out.

Comment: So I would be using a selector with `TextView` inside it instead of `Item`?

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/my_shape"` instead of this `android:background="@drawable/my_selector"` and you need to make two separate drawable shape file for normal state and selected state. as shown in that answer from the link.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. Is it possible for me to access `R.id.admin` from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in the java class? When I do a normal findViewById (after I've called the getMenuInflater) it comes back as null. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding below code in your menu item:

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
android:orderInCategory="50"
```

`50` is just a random number.

You can configure the ActionBar styles and properties by creating ActionBar theme styles.
Read more at:
[Custom ActionBar Styles](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Extended-ActionBar-Guide#custom-actionbar-styles)

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

You have to use the app namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/user_level"
  android:title="Administrator"
  app:showAsAction="withText" />
</menu>
```

**Question 2**

You cannot use menu to do that. What you can do is to use `AppBarLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--Your normal content-->
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: *You cannot use menu*...  Why not? Isn't that what `android:actionLayout` is for?